# how can i put a tdatetime into a stringlist object?

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to add a `TDateTime` value into a `TStringList` object using Delphi 10.4 Sydney.

I managed to do it like this:

```pascal
TDateTimeObj = class(TObject)
strict private
  DT: TDateTime;
protected
public
  constructor Create(FDateTime: TDateTime);
  property DateTime: TDateTime read DT write DT;
end;

constructor TDateTimeObj.Create(FDateTime: TDateTime);
begin
  Self.DT := FDateTime;
end;
```

Then I add it to the `TStringList` like this:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  b: TStringList;
begin
  b := TStringList.Create;    
  b.AddObject('a', TDateTimeObj.Create(now));    
  b.AddObject('b', TDateTimeObj.Create(now));    
  FreeAndNil(b);
end;
```

It works, but when I close the program I have a memory leak as I did not free the `TDateTimeObj` objects.

Is there a way to free the objects automatically, or a better way to achieve the same result?

Comment: The answer is given [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Classes.TStringList.AddObject).

Comment: Ok, I have to create the tstringlist like this b := TStringList.Create(true); so that the objects will be freed automatically at the end. thanks

Comment: Also, don't forget your `try..finally` blocks! Otherwise you'll leak on an exception, forgotten `Exit` etc.

Comment: Why don't you just use a TDictionary<string, TDateTime>? Then you don't need this wrapper class!

Comment: @DelphiCoder It depends on your needs. A list is ordered, a dictionary is not.

Comment: Actually, in a 64-bit app, you can just put the `TDateTime` value in the object pointer.

Comment: @DelphiCoder Additionally, a list can contain duplicate strings, while a dictionary can't.

Comment: @Olivier Everything true, to be fair. But we don't know the needs of lorife

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to make the string list own the added objects. Owned objects are destroyed when the string list is destroyed.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var b: TStringList;
begin
  b := TStringList.Create(TRUE);     // TRUE means OwnObjects
  try
    b.AddObject('a', TDateTimeObj.Create(now));    
    b.AddObject('b', TDateTimeObj.Create(now));    
  finally
    FreeAndNil(b);                     // Owned objects will be destroyed as well
  end;
end;
```

Comment: `FreeAndNil` on a local variableis not needed. Simply using `b.Free;` is more clean.

Comment: thanks. could you tell me when I should use FreeAndNil then?

Comment: That is a controversial question. I always use FreeAndNil to protect myself against code update. With FreeAndNil to are sure to get an access violation if you use the object after having freed it. So when I write code, even if that day FreeAndNil is not necessary, I use it anyway. Tomorrow when I update the code I will easier detect my errors (using the object after having freed it) which otherwise are much more difficult to track.